# What's fixed with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I installed Windows 7 RC, but really I just didn't see much difference between it and Vista.  I was an early adopter of Vista and will admit that at first it stepped on a couple of devices due to missing drivers, however besides that it's always been as stable as XP for me.  So really, for those who have been cheering about Windows 7, what's it doing for you?  Why is it better and what do you think will tempt me to upgrade?

Comment: nothings really fixed..they've just disabled some of the hidden features of Vista..

Comment: Why do you install things without reading about what you install? It's all explained in the documentation you see before you even end up with the installer, unless you obtain the installer through some non-official way.

Answer (score 5):

It's basically Vista done right. Not only has the UI been cleaned up and polished in many areas, but it boots faster, is more responsive, and uses much less memory. (Oh, and it takes advantage of multi-core processors better, but I don't know if that applies to you.) On top of that, most drivers are now available through Windows Update, which is really convenient. Also, the media stuff was greatly improved; for example, Windows Media Player 12 supports many codecs such as DivX and AAC right off the bat, and the media sharing feature was improved.

All-in-all it's just an even better version of Windows Vista. Whether that sounds like something you'd want to spend money on is up to you.

Comment: While it is good to have a functional and stable operating system, it does seem like this should just be Vista SP3. I've recommended Win7 to all of my XP and Vista friends, but I don't think Microsoft should be able to cash in. Even Apple (of all companies!) is not charging more than $30 for their refresh this time.

Answer (score 3):

[Features new to Windows 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7). Though for me personally, its that Windows 7 is a bit more polished, UAC is less intrusive, and Media Center "works better" with network-shared media resources. Other than the printer I need to replace anyway, everything "just worked" as far as drivers go (on a ~1 yr old Dell laptop).

Comment: Not to mention the speed.

Comment: The hardware I have Win7 on is a late '07 model laptop, no noticable speed increase (or decrease) from Vista to me. I suppose that's good - it is rather mediocre hardware.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of "what's fixed" I would say the user experience. It is a much more pleasant OS to use, it feels responsive.  In terms of what's new, here are some of my favorite features from the Beta/RC:

### Media

It has better video codec support out of the box (mpg, mp4, avchd (mts), xvid, etc)
Media Center does some basic Transcoding, so you can watch the above video formats on an extender (such as an Xbox 360).
Media Center/Media Player support (unprotected) AAC audio files
Stream media from your pc over the internet
Play media to a shared device (remotely control media being played on another computer/device

### Libraries / Home Group

You can group similar files in different locations into Libraries.  These libraries can also be shared with other computers in your Home Group (simplified file sharing / networking of computer).

### UI

The task bar is now a combination of the task bar and the quick launch bar.
Aero Peek - mouse over the icon in the task bar and get a list of windows for that application.  Mouse over the application windows and you can peek at the open application (all other windows become transparent outlines)
Aero Peek also works with Alt+Tab

### Better Performance

Benchmarks are showing better performance (though marginal).  However the User Experience has improved in a way that the OS is perceived as being much more responsive than Vista.
Better use of multiple cores

Answer (score 1):

I have moved on from Vista to Windows 7, here are some of my observations:

The security management is more fine tuned. In Vista I have to use "run as administrator" to execute a batch file that just moves some files, but that's not needed in Windows 7.

The new taskbar really works quite well. It's easier to see what's running and to find recent documents.

Functions like connecting to a network and detaching devices is easier and clearer.

The memory usage is smaller. I installed it on a Samsung NC10 mini laptop, I would not even try to install Vista on it.

Answer (score 1):

Bloat

Bare install of Vista tops out to 12Gb or something of hard drive space.

Windows 7 install is a only a couple of Gigs.

less bloat == more speed (hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

First of all it runs on much lighter hardware, making old laptops useful gifts for family members

Certain UI bits have been tweaked and fine-tuned making it feel more finished (like the taskbar and network settings)

But indeed if you know Vista, Windows 7 isn't a whole lot different, though there is more than meets the eye

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I am in the same boat you were at first:  I actually grew to like Vista over XP, and I didn't really have any problems with it.

When I tried Win7, I was really wondering how it was having such great press while Vista was having such *horrible* press.

After using it more though, it just has way more *polish*.   It has a lot of small tweaks to usability and visuals that just make it feel a lot nicer.   It has some great window management features, and the new taskbar is a pretty good improvement.

Plus, the speed issue is a big deal for people, but frankly I didn't notice much difference (outside of startup time, which is a lot faster).

I don't really have a fast PC, it's a few years old (Core 2 Duo E6600), and Vista has never felt slow to me, so I didn't really notice any big speed changes in Win7.   I do have 8GB of memory though (for software development), so I think that is probably why I never had problems with memory-hungry Vista.    Frankly I think Vista isn't really all so slow, it just needs a lot of memory (and ANYTHING gets really slow when you have to go to the disk often).