# Windows Vista Vs. Windows 7 - What are the best improvement?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any compelling reasons for upgrading Vista to Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/19393/any-compelling-reasons-for-upgrading-vista-to-windows-7)

I heard a lot about the graphical changes and about the user-friendlyness but I would like to know a lot more from that operating system. I would like to implement it in our IT environment but still need to be convinced. I am using some home-made applications and I already know it's not "ok" with Vista.

Please, let's talk about the plus Windows 7 has over Vista.

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/19393/any-compelling-reasons-for-upgrading-vista-to-windows-7

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/11647/whats-fixed-with-windows-7 http://superuser.com/questions/4287/windows-7-features-not-found-in-previous-versions and probably others. ;)

Comment: Please do not remove duplicate links in questions that have been closed. The closure was correct and this is indeed a duplicate.